# How to get the part of a URL without protocol nor domain

Tags: python, django

I have URLs of the form

```
http://example.com/example/a/b/c.html
https//www.example.com/
```

How do I get the path from the server root, without protocol or domain name? With the examples above, the function should return:

```
/example/a/b/c.html
/
```

(I am using Django: answers relying on this framework are accepted!)

Comment: maybe just simple regex? `(https?|ftp).+?\w(\/.*)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) module can solve this:

```
from urlparse import urlparse # for python 2
from urllib.parse import urlparse # for python 3

parsed_url = urlparse('http://example.com/abc/cde')
assert parsed_url.path == '/abc/cde'
```

Comment: Not sure why, but `urlparse('www.web.com/commercial/composite').path` get's me `www.web.com/commercial/composite`, which is not ideal

Comment: I suspect that's caused by the lack of scheme (`https://` or just `//`):
https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `path` attribute of django `HttpRequest` object, in other words:

```
request.path
```

see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path) for more

Comment: Django uses urllib internally (`grep -ri urllib path/to/django/django`). From my point of view this answers apporach is therefore preferable, as you don't need to repeat what already happend before (as long as you want to use it inside of views).